# Timer in WCF server gets duplicated every time

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, timer

I have a WCF service that I host in Windows Azure. I use a Timer in this server and every 10 seconds the server needs to update something. The server is implemented in a ASP application and a WPF application.

When I initialize the Timer in the contructor like this:

```
public Service1()
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(WCFService_Elapsed);
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Start();
}
```

The timer will be started but if I restart the application the timers will run faster(because it runs a duplicate of the timer). Declare the timer above the contructor as a private property doesn't do the trick.

I already tried to use it in the OnStart method from the ServiceBase class:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(WCFService_Elapsed);
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }
```

But this get never called... I also tested a static timer but that does not get started either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A WCF service is not something that "lives", it gets called once and then is discarded until called again. It's a really bad place to place a timer, that by definition needs to be alive for a long time. Your service code looks like a windows service to me though. Can you explain what this code is and where it goes?

Comment: Why not use a windows service if you want something akin to a WCF service with the ability to remain active and do "work" per a timer.

Here's a short tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0

Comment: @nvoigt It's a school project, it needs to be a WCF service and it is ment to be a tamagotchi, all of the logic is in de WCF service. The ASP en WPF application are only displaying the tamagotchi's and give them food etc. The WCFService_Elapsed method randomizes the stats every 10 seconds in the database. Due this the tamagotichis could die and you are force to interact with them.

Comment: Can you go into more detail what exactly is WCF about your service? Because it sounds and reads like a normal windows service.

Comment: @nvoigt I don't know what you mean, I guess you are confused because I used the OnStart method that is not a standard WCF method. I used this Method as a test but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, then maybe you are using a WCF service. A WCF service is the wrong spot to place a timer. I explained that in comment #1. You need to host your timer in a place that has a static lifetime. A WCF service will be called and be gone after that.

Comment: @nvoigt Do you have a suggestion? is it a good idea to let one of the interfaces(ASP or WPF) run a Timer and with every tick(after 10 sec) call the randomizeStat method?

Comment: No, if you *need* a timer, you will have to run a windows service or a separate executable.

Comment: I don't really need a timer it's not a requirement but, I couldn't think of a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Timer inherits IDisposable, which means Timer can and should be disposed.

I am surprised that when closing your service the timer is still running, but you should dispose at when stopping the service to fix your problem.

So in your OnStop Method you should call:

```
timer.Stop();
timer.Dispose();
```

Comment: If by any reason OnStop shouldnt be called either you can make your Service1 class inherit from IDisposable and do the timer.Stop() and timer.Dispose(); in your Dispose-Method.

Comment: The Onstop method doesn´t work at al, this is because it is a WCF application it does not standard implement ServiceBase. If I inherit from Idisposable I will receive a StackOverflowException.